# Multithreading Lime in Python

Tags: python, keras, parallel-processing, lime

I am new in using python. I am trying to run the lime explainer for more than 10000 samples. I am using a 1D-CNN keras model to explain.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Activation, Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

a = np.array([[0,1,2,9,3], [0,5,1,33,6], [1, 12,1,8,9]])
train = np.reshape(a[:,1:],(a[:,1:].shape[0], a[:,1:].shape[1],1))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(a[:,:1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=(train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                 optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False),
                 metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train, y_train, epochs=3, verbose=1)
```

```
import lime
import lime.lime_tabular
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.RecurrentTabularExplainer(train, training_labels=y_train ,
                                                        class_names=['0','1'], feature_names=['feat'])

result = []
def explain_lime(model_keras, input, numFeatures):
    for i in range(train.shape[0]):
        explanation = explainer.explain_instance(input[i], model.predict, num_samples=numFeatures)
        expMat = explanation.as_list()
        result.append(expMat)
    return print(f'{i} finished.')

explain_lime(model_keras=model,input=train , numFeatures=4) # works well
```

How can I do this with a multiprocessing libraries. I tried some solution but unsuccessfully

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend="threading")(map(delayed(explain_lime), model, train, 5))

results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend="threading")(map(delayed(explain_lime), model, train, 5))
TypeError: 'Sequential' object is not iterable
```

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=40)
results = pool.map(explain_lime(model, train, 5))

TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'
```

I don't understand if the error comes from my code or from the lime function that is not compatible .

Comment: you can't...this depend on the task scheduler of your OS

Comment: I don't have a scheduler (e.g.slurm) on my server. It runs the job on a single cpu by default

Comment: I'm talking about the task scheduler of your operating system. Each OS has its own task scheduler running in the kernel space and which manage task execution you cannot predict its work. Even 2 différent process can be executed inside one CPU etc

Comment: So I can't execute lime explanation functions in parallel without knowing how my scheduler works?

Comment: you can do multitasking but true parallelism is not possible inside one process in python and if you create many process their execution also depend on the task scheduler....they can be executed in parallel or not only the OS knows. My suggestion: look at threading or multiprocessing library in python.

Comment: I will rephrase my question. Tanks